# jQuery event delegation behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a bit confused about the behavior of the event delegation for, in my case - the `click` event. It doesn't work using the `$(document)...` or the `$({any DOM element higher than the selected one to set the event handler on})...` syntax. The selector, which I'm gonna set the `click` handler on, exists.

That's what I was doing:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select .triangle', function(e) {
    console.log($(this), e.target);
});

// OR

$('.select').on('click', '.triangle', function(e) {
    console.log($(this), e.target);
});
```

None of these two worked. Note, that it's a dynamically created element and all it's parts, starting from the `.select` element, is created by `JS`, not `HTML`.

**EDIT 1:** Added `.v-hidden` class to the `CSS`.

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  let $this = $(this),
    numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('v-hidden');

  // Wrap the select element in a div
  let $selectWrapper = $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

  if ($('.modal-box-default').is(':visible')) {
    $('.select').addClass('modal-box-full-width');
  }

  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  $this.after('<div class="styled-select"></div>');

  let $styledSelect = $this.next();

  // Show the first select option in the styled div

  //$styledSelect.text($this.children('option:eq(0)').text());
  $styledSelect.text('wefwefewfwefwqwdwqdwqdefew');
  $('.select').append('<div class="triangle"></div>');

  // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
  let $list = $('<ul class="options">').insertAfter($styledSelect);

  // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li>', {
      html: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      value: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  let $listItems = $list.children('li');







  // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)

  /***************************/
  /* WHY BOTH OF THESE DON'T WORK?
  /***************************/

  /*
       $(document).on('click', '.select .triangle', function(e) {
         console.log($(this), e.target);
       });
   */

  /*
        $('.select').on('click', '.triangle', function(e) {
          console.log($(this), e.target);
        });
  */





  // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
  // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
  $listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
  $(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.v-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.modal-box-full-width {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 1rem -2.4rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  min-width: 10rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 50vw;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  height: 3.2rem;
}

.styled-select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  width: calc(100% - 3rem);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.select .triangle {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.select .triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  border-top: .5rem solid #333;
  border-left: .5rem solid transparent;
  border-right: .5rem solid transparent;
}

.modal-box-default {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 30rem;
  min-width: 10rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 1.4rem 2.4rem 2.4rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: max-height .7s;
  transition: max-height .7s;
  width: 50vw;
  z-index: 4;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.options li {
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: green;
}

.options li:hover {
  background-color: #39f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-box-default">
  <select id="add-playlist-expiration-date" name="add_playlist_expiration_date">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    <option value="4"></option>
    <option value="5"></option>
    <option value="6"></option>
    <option value="7"></option>
    <option value="8"></option>
    <option value="9"></option>
    <option value="10"></option>
    <option value="11"></option>
    <option value="12"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What you really want to do? change `.select .triangle` to `.select, .triangle` to make it work

Comment: I tried following the code and got lost...what is the purpose of this overtly complex code? It looks as if the behavior and outcome (whatever they may be) are simple, yet there is not one expression or statement that does anything directly., plus there is the style declaration missing for `.v-hidden`... I think...What is your objective?

Comment: I've tried to use a small snippet so you can understand better. It's not a big block of code, I've removed a whole bunch of it for the StackOverflow. The purpose is the ability to style the `<select>` element and also, make it accessible by the screen readers. That's why there is a `.s-hidden` class there. Sorry if this is not in the `CSS`, didn't want to include it if it's not about the current problem.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. The weird wrapping, hiding, and styling of a select is necessary due to the fact that browser have many inconsistencies for custom styling select tags (as well as other form controls too). You are doing what plugins like [select2](https://select2.org/) does only on a smaller scale. But I have to disagree with your point about `.v-hidden` (in your reply it's now `.s-hidden`?) class. It needs to be included in CSS because it's not worth making assumptions over what it is (although it is aptly named). There might be an extra property that is overlooked or whatever.

Comment: Heh, yee :) Sorry about the `.s-hidden`, it's `.v-hidden` for `visibility: hidden;`. I thought about the screen reader thing and said that.  Do you think the problem is inside the JS? Could wrong HTML or CSS do this in my particular case?

Comment: Yes, to everything, styling a select to conform to all major browsers *and* be accessible is a tall order. You are on the right track, though. Since `display: none` is out of the question (not access friendly) but `visibility` and `opacity` can still allow the original select to interfere in the flow, try syncing a `<label for='selID'>` to the original and then use `text-indent:-9999` or `left:111111` (direction and distance after `2000px` is arbitrary) on the original select and wrap the new select in that label.

Comment: Could you show me the example, please? I've tried using the `text-indent: -9999rem`, `left: 999999rem`. None of them worked. I know the position changing property `left` won't work without the correct position value but it's still the same. I don't get what you trying to say about the `<label...>` thing. What's the purpose of that? It's just the same as I used to name the `<input...>` field, isn't it? I'll try to find another solution. I could easily achieve what I'd want to by using the `$('.select').on('click', function() { ... });` and I wouldn't need this thread but the curiosity thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow! :) Finally, I figured it out.

The problem was the little `z-index: -1` rule. It appears that using this rule with the `position: absolute` won't work correctly. You have to remove the rule or the position value.